# Error loading config file: .dockercfg: $HOME is not defined

Tags: server, vmware

After the VM(VMware) crashed, I tried to start Synapse and got the following errors:

```
Dec 18 11:05:20 systemd[1]: Stopped Synapse server.
Dec 18 11:05:20 systemd[1]: Starting Synapse server...
Dec 18 11:05:20 matrix-synapse[44775]: WARNING: Error loading config file: .dockercfg: $HOME is not defined
Dec 18 11:05:20 matrix-synapse[44775]: Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: matrix-synapse: No such container: matrix-synapse
Dec 18 11:05:20 matrix-synapse[44798]: WARNING: Error loading config file: .dockercfg: $HOME is not defined
Dec 18 11:05:20 matrix-synapse[44798]: Error: No such container: matrix-synapse
Dec 18 11:05:20 systemd[1]: Started Synapse server.
Dec 18 11:05:20 matrix-synapse[44806]: WARNING: Error loading config file: .dockercfg: $HOME is not defined
Dec 18 11:05:20 matrix-synapse[44806]: docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /matrix/synapse/config.
Dec 18 11:05:20 matrix-synapse[44806]: See 'docker run --help'.
Dec 18 11:05:20 systemd[1]: matrix-synapse.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=125/n/a
```

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64). The second VM(Ubuntu 18) has the same error.

Comment: I have the same issue with hassio:
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: no, sorry - I don't know what cmd is run

I have the same issue with hassio:
```
hassio-supervisor[3672384]: WARNING: Error loading config file: .dockercfg: $HOME is not defined
hassio-supervisor[3672398]: Error: No such object: hassio_supervisor
hassio-supervisor[3672420]: Error: No such container: hassio_supervisor
hassio-supervisor[3672436]: "docker run" requires at least 1 argument.
hassio-supervisor[3672436]: See 'docker run --help'.
hassio-supervisor[3672436]: Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
hassio-supervisor[3672436]: Run a command in a new container
```